# Calling base class method in Python

Tags: python, class

I have two classes A and B and A is base class of B.

I read that all methods in Python are virtual.

So how do I call a method of the base because when I try to call it, the method of the derived class is called as expected?

```
>>> class A(object):
    def print_it(self):
        print 'A'


>>> class B(A):
    def print_it(self):
        print 'B'


>>> x = B()
>>> x.print_it()
B
>>> x.A ???
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Using [super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def print_it(self):
...             print 'A'
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def print_it(self):
...             print 'B'
... 
>>> x = B()
>>> x.print_it()                # calls derived class method as expected
B
>>> super(B, x).print_it()      # calls base class method
A
```

Answer (score 40):

Two ways:

```
>>> A.print_it(x)
'A'
>>> super(B, x).print_it()
'A'
```

Comment: Is the first way passing `x` as the self parameter? I didn't know you could do that...

Comment: @Wilduck. Good question, do you know the answer on that one?

Comment: Yes, you pass `x` as the self parameter. When you use the method on an instantiated object, like `x.print_it()`, `x` is automaticaly given as the `self` parameter. When you use the original function from the class definition (`A.print_it`), `A` is not an instantiated object of type `A`, so it does not give as parameter `A` and expect a value for the parameter `self`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
super().print_it()
```

Comment: That would work when used inside the class, but the question shows a use case outside the class.